# CSS and JS is not loading in new theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

Created a new template and it's showing in the back end, but the CSS and JS files are not loading.

The default theme **blank/luma** works fine, but when I select new theme then CSS, JS is not loading and when I run the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I get the following Compilation from source:

> frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract/en_US/css/styles-l.less variable
>   @button__shadow-active is undefined in file
>   /chroot/home/installs/xxxxxxx/html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/MyStore/My‌​Abstract/en_US/css/source/_extends.less
>   in _extends.less on line 37, column 30 35| } 36| &:active { 37|
>   .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow-active); 38| } 39| } 40| >

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining the variable hasn't been set, have you made any changes in this theme? If so then you must have made an error, if you haven't made any changes then try deleting the var/view_preprocessed and pub/static/frontend directories and running `php bin/magento static-content:deploy` command again